# document.getElementById() returns null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a library for JS that allows the creation and deletion and editing of widgets. When you create a new widget, it automatically gets an id like "widget5" or whatever is the next number in the array. On deletion, document.getElementById() can't find the id and returns null.

I realize there are a lot of questions about this problem, and the answer usually has to do with the JavaScript loading before the page, but since the widget library I am writing adds widgets after the page is loaded, that shouldn't be the problem.

I think the problem is that when creating a widget using JS, the JS can't find it for some reason. For example, if I hard-coded in a widget the JS has no problem finding the id. How can I fix this?

Any help is much appreciated!

http://codepen.io/amstrudy/pen/grxpOK

```
    //this is just the function that is supposed to find the id, check the codepen above for the full code

    function deleteWidget(){
        var widget = document.getElementById("delList");
        widget = widget.options[widget.selectedIndex].text;
        window.alert(widget);
        widget = document.getElementById(widget);
        window.alert(widget);
        document.getElementById("body").removeChild(widget);
    }
```

Comment: please add  code which adds widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a space inside your widget ids:

```
div.setAttribute("id", " widget" + widgetNum);
                       ^ here
```

Comment: It does.. When you remove the space, everything works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKJOyj I get that there are better/other ways to fix this, but this is the main cause of the bug.

Comment: No reason to be. As you can notice, it is the only troublesome space. :)

Answer (score 0):

The value of selected option is stored in `value` atttribute:

```
widget = widget.options[widget.selectedIndex].value; // instead of .text
```

Comment: While you're correct, in this particular example, both the value and the text are exactly the same as they're populated by `delList.options[delList.options.length] = new Option(" widget" + (widgetNum - 1), " widget" + (widgetNum - 1))`

Comment: I think OP must apply both solutions, because using the `value` attribute is more correct, so he can use an arbitrary option titles as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a leading space within the id .

**In your deleteWidget function change :**

```
widget = document.getElementById(widget);
```

**to :**

```
widget = document.getElementById(" " + widget);
```

**or just remove the space**

```
div.setAttribute("id", "widget" + widgetNum);
```

fixed here : http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/XKabpj

Hope this helps